# There are several questions here which are basically from a current ($2021$-$2022$ round $1$) USAMTS math contest

Tags: support, contests

The year $33$ online [USAMTS $2021$-$2021$ round $1$ contest](https://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_33_1.pdf) has a submit by date of October $18$, $2021$. However, although users are not allowed to ask questions online about it, there are $2$ questions related to it from one user, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4248086/602049) (currently deleted by the OP) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4247538/602049). There's also this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4248831/602049) that was just recently posted, with it being basically the same as the first listed one by the other user.

Please keep in mind this contest's questions, and try to avoid answering any posted questions that are basically the same, at least until after Oct. $18$.

Comment: Are the question present in https://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_33_1.pdf only cominh in USAMTS because I can't find the second question you linked in the pdf with a quick `Ctrl` + `F`

Comment: @JitendraSingh I assume "cominh" is meant to be "coming". As for the second question I linked to, the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247538/proving-that-any-subset-of-size-7-or-its-complement-from-the-set-of-1-2-3#comment8832715_4247538) there from [Snacc](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/617984/snacc) states it is "very related to a problem 2" (which is labeled as "2/1/33"). Note the questions asked here have been changed somewhat, I guess mainly to help avoid anyone finding they come from that contest.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our notice! This is an annual problem. [A list of related past threads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=USAMTS). I will use my voting powers somewhat harshly when protecting the integrity of contests like USAMTS.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're welcome. You may wish to also thank Snacc in a comment since, without their comments, I wouldn't have known that the first $2$ questions, (as well as my answer to the first one, and the third question due to how similar it is to that first one) were from that contest. Also, FYI, since I don't know how long it might take for Stefan Albrecht to delete their answer to the second linked question, or for a moderator to do it for that answer or the entire post, I've voted to delete the answer to help "hide" it from most people more quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  We do have a policy on Math SE of locking contest problems and temporarily deleting any answers.  Please raise flags when you see such questions (with a link to the competition page (or to this thread) in the flag).  I'll try to keep an eye out for such flags.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250169/here-are-2-problems-i-need-help-on-i-tried-some-strategies-to-these-2-problems) is another post taken from this source.

Comment: I think I've caught [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250071/a-lucas-sequence) which was unfortunately *answered* as well. We *have* to ask for sources for contest questions : preferably sources which are net-accessible. I'm not happy with this happening, particularly a fairly reputed user engaging in these shenanigans.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I'm the user who answered that question. I'd like to prevent it from happening again, so if you don't mind me asking, how does one see a question is a *contest question*? Is is because the question itself is a formatted as a quotation?

Comment: @Mastrem It's  bad luck, don't worry. Of course the "contest-math" tag is applicable , but my take on it is this : search for the question using either Approach0 or SearchOnMath first to confirm that it's not a duplicate, and then search for "keywords" of the question on Google or something. If you can't find anything that convinces you that the question can be answered nicely, then please ask for the source of the question. If you don't get a reply, then abstain from answering. I think we can only do so much, so I sympathise with you. Having a verifiable source for contest questions is a must

Comment: In this case, I'd read the meta post here so I recognized the question immediately. That's why I sort of jumped into the question so quickly : I also know users who post contest questions often so I keep looking out for their questions, and find out which questions have a source isn't clearly given. When I spot a problematic question, I report it and we come full circle.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Well at least I found out about two cool math search engines I didn't know about before :)

Comment: @Mastrem Those engines will save about 75% of your time on this site for searching out questions. You can use it to spot duplicates well.

Comment: @Mastrem I'm sorry, I should have realized. The shenanigans I referred to , in my first comment, were directed at the OP of that question who has about 12.3K rep, and not you, so I hope you were not offended by this. Whatever, the OP there should have known far better, and ,in my opinion should face some action.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh, I got that and wasn't offended, don't worry about it. Just somewhat annoyed the OP of that question made me waste my time and effort, which might've unconsciously influenced the tone of my original comment.

Comment: For anybody interested, [How to prove that there exists any non negative integral solution to this equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4254298/602049) is one more try to get an answer for question #$4$ of the contest, as also tried in my first & third linked posts in my question here.