# USAMTS Discussion Policy

Tags: discussion, contests

I see that discussion has “opened” (solutions posted to some of the problems) for this years USAMTS round 2 as the due date was November 28th. **Close the discussion as soon as possible**. Although the due date is November 28th, discussion is not permitted until a few days later. People can still technically ask for an extension that can last up to 24 hours, so some people may have not yet submitted. I regret forgetting to mention this [in my last post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35301), but **discussion of problems is only allowed when it’s allowed on AoPS**. It’s generally safe to discuss at ~12 AM GMT *2 days after the due date*. In the case of this round, discussion should be safe on November 30th at 4 PM PST/7 PM EST if you live in the US.

Comment: I assume that by "close the discussion" you mean that the questions should be locked - as described here: ["Contest problem" policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774). Since this is a thing only a moderator can do, a natural question is whether you have already raise a mod flag (or flags) pointing out the relevant posts. (Of course, it is useful that there is a post on meta, too - so that it can be discussed what can be appropriate action in the future instances.)

Comment: I have included a link to the previous post on meta - I hope that's ok. I assume then you meant [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35301) when you wrote "in my last post". (Including some context is useful for the readers of your question.)